# Turn a variable from string to integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a problem with the int() function.
I tried to use it in a simple program, but remains not working.
This is my short program.
I use int() to turn the a variable from a str into a int.
And use it to compeare with 2. But it returns an error, because i**t's still seen a as a str**. What's happening??

```
a = '4'
int (a)
if a > 2:
    print( "It's working" )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int(a)` doesn't mutate `a`, it creates a new object and returns it. Try this:

```
a = '4'
i = int(a)
if i > 2:
    print("It's working")
```

Notice that the new variable I created on line 2 has a different name from the one I created on line 1. It doesn't have to. In fact, sometimes it can be more readable to re-use the name:

```
a = '4'     # Now `a` is a `str`
a = int(a)  # Now `a` is an `int`
if a > 2:
    print("It's working")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# or mutate the a by redefining a:
a = '4'
a = int(a)
if a > 2:
    print("It's working")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **type casting** it before the **for loop**, you can keep **"a"** as a **str** and just type cast it to int **in** the for loop. This will preserve your **str dataype** while you will get your desired output.

```
a = '4'

if int(a) > 2:
    print( "It's working" )
```

In your program. you are converting str to int only for that instance. You're not storing it anywhere. So your **variable a** points to the str which is stored before type casting it.